# How to call a method in a method?

Tags: c#, methods

Here I am trying to return a string from the method `MapFinder()` and use the String returned from the method to use in an another condition in `MapTracker()`.

```
public String MapFinder()
{
    if ((Map.Width == 8 && Map.Height==8))
    {
        return "DefaultMap";
    }
    else
        return "Something Different";
}

public String MapTracker()
{
    if(StringFromMapFinder == "DefaultMap");
    {
        return "Hello DefaultMap";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Hello StrangeMap";
    }
```

Comment: try this `if(StringFromMapFinder == MapFinder())`

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html

Comment: Why are you downvoting? This question is trivial to C# experts, but please note that: (1) question title is correct (2) readable code with author's attempt is provided (3) the attempt is clearly and precisely described in the text. So, why a downvote?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl it is extremely easy to find the answer to this question by googling "C# call method" - the OP presumably did not do any research before asking this question at all - I would think that's why it was downvoted

Comment: hm.. looking at like that, can't argue with it.

Comment: Thanks quetzalcoatl. And BrokenGlass, I did googling but with other terms like the question heading. I just wanted an answer for my situation and I am sure it won't take a minute for an expert to answer in two or three lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it almost exactly as you described, you were just lacking a few bits.  After some minimal fixing, your code would be:

```
public String MapFinder()
{
    if ((Map.Width == 8 && Map.Height==8))
    {
        return "DefaultMap";
    }
    else
        return "Something Different";
}

public String MapTracker()
{
    if( MapFinder() == "DefaultMap" ) // <- change
    {
        return "Hello DefaultMap";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Hello StrangeMap"; // <- change
    }
}
```

I've marked the changes. I've made three:

- fixed typo: you've got a `;` in first `if` instead of `)`
- fixed typo: you've got an unclosed quotes `"` in strangemap
- I've replaced `StringFromMapFinder` with **a method call**

However, usually, you will rather want to store the result of that call somewhere and later inspect it:

```
public String MapTracker()
{
    String mapFinderResult;
    mapFinderResult = MapFinder();
    if( mapFinderResult == "DefaultMap" )
    {
        return "Hello DefaultMap";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Hello StrangeMap";
    }
}
```

Here, I've created a variable named `mapFinderResult`, the I've called the method and stored the result in that variable, and then in `if` I've used the variable to check what was returned. This longer version is just the same as previous, just with the difference that the result is stored in variable instead of being directly used in `if` condition.

I won't describe it more because I'd need to write a very long lesson. Please fetch some C# tutorial and read further about `methods` `calling methods` and `using variables`.

Answer (score 0):

You would call the method `MapFinder()` inside `MapTracker()`

```
public string MapFinder()
{
    if ((Map.Width == 8 && Map.Height == 8))
    {
        return "DefaultMap";
    }
    return "Something Different";
}

public string MapTracker()
{
        // call the method, include the "()"
        if(MapFinder() == "DefaultMap");
        {
               return "Hello DefaultMap";
        }

        return "Hello StrangeMap";
}
```